# Input fields validation in contact form - HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
//Contact Form Redirection
var form = document.getElementById("my-form");

async function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(event.target);
  fetch(event.target.action, {
    method: form.method,
    body: data,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).finally(() => {
    window.location = "thankyou.html";
  });
}
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)

//Contact Form Error Animation 
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  var isValid = true;
  this.querySelectorAll('input, textarea').forEach(function (f) {
    if (!f.checkValidity()) {
      isValid = false;
      f.style.borderColor = "red";
      f.style.animation = "shake 0.82s forwards";
      setTimeout(function () { f.style.animation = "unset"; }, 820);
    } else {
      f.style.borderColor = "initial";
    }
  })
  if (!isValid) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```css
/* Contact Form */

input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="https://formspree.io/f/xdobkgny" id="my-form" method="POST" novalidate>
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your First Name.." required>
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your Last Name.." required>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate.." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The form is running fine except it redirects to a page when there is no input in the field and when the error is thrown. Basically, it should not redirect me to a page when there is nothing typed in the input fields whereas its redirecting me to `thankyou.html` even when there is nothing in the input fields.

See this clip for the output I'm getting:

https://watch.screencastify.com/v/BSkuGitl5ACHDWEvGziM

How can I avoid this?

### Update

https://watch.screencastify.com/v/RkgLmLAGztVduI26LV55

the animation does not work on one input field and I also would like the "please fill out this field" message to be removed and only have the shake animation

### UPDATE2

Apparently, this is the JS code that sends the responses to email, so can you use this to make changes to your code?

```
var form = document.getElementById("my-form");

async function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(event.target);
  fetch(event.target.action, {
    method: form.method,
    body: data,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).finally(() => {
    window.location = "thankyou.html";
  });
}
myform.firstname.oninvalid = badEntrie
myform.lastname.oninvalid = badEntrie
myform.email.oninvalid = badEntrie
myform.subject.oninvalid = badEntrie

function badEntrie({ target }) {
  target.classList.add('shakingErr')
  setTimeout(() => { target.classList.remove('shakingErr') }, 820)
}
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)
```

Comment: `novalidate` ignore the validation and submit the form. `preventDefault` doesn't really stop you to submitting the form if invalid, also no element with id `my-form-status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that :

```js
const form = document.forms.myform // HTML: <form name="myform" 
  ;
form.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  let data = Object.fromEntries( new FormData(form).entries())

  let validationOK = true
  for (let entrie in data) 
    {
    if (!form[entrie].checkValidity())
      {
      validationOK = false
      form[entrie].classList.add('shakingErr') 
      setTimeout(() => { form[entrie].classList.remove('shakingErr') }, 820)
      }
    }
  if (validationOK)
    {
    fetch( form.action,
      { method: 'POST'
      , headers:
        { 'Accept'       : 'application/json'
        , 'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
      , body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
    .finally(() => { window.location = 'thankyou.html' })
    }
  }
```

```css
input,
select,
textarea {
  width         : 100%;
  padding       : 12px;
  border        : 1px solid #555;
  margin-top    : 6px;
  margin-bottom : 16px;
  resize        : vertical;
  }
textarea {
  height        : 170px;
  }
button {
  background-color : #0563bb;
  color            : white;
  padding          : 12px 20px;
  border           : none;
  cursor           : pointer;
  }
button:before {
  content        : attr(type);
  text-transform : capitalize;
  }
button:hover {
  opacity : 0.9;
  }
.contactform {
  position                  : relative;
  border-radius             : 50px;
  background-color          : #f2f2f2;
  padding                   : 5px;
  z-index                   : 2;
  display                   : block;
  margin-left               : auto;
  margin-right              : auto;
  margin-bottom             : auto;
  margin-top                : 1%;
  width                     : 100%;
  animation-name            : gradient;
  animation-duration        : 3s;
  animation-iteration-count : infinite;
  }
.contactform:hover {
  animation-name            : gradient;
  animation-duration        : 15s;
  animation-iteration-count : infinite;
  }
div.contactform > div:not(.row) {
  text-align : center;
  }
.column {
  float        : center;
  width        : 50%;
  margin-top   : 6px;
  padding      : 20px;
  display      : block;
  margin-left  : auto;
  margin-right : auto;
  }
.row:after {
  content : "";
  display : table;
  clear   : both;
  }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  button {
    width      : auto;
    margin-top : 0;
    }
  }
.shakingErr {
  border-color: red;
  animation   : shake 0.82s forwards;
}
@keyframes shake {
  10%,90%     { transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0); }
  20%,80%     { transform: translate3d( 2px, 0, 0); }
  30%,50%,70% { transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0); }
  40%,60%     { transform: translate3d( 4px, 0, 0); }
  }
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div>
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="https://formspree.io/f/xdobkgny" method="POST" novalidate >
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input name="firstname" type="text"  placeholder="Your First Name.." required>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input  name="lastname" type="text"  placeholder="Your Last Name.." required>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input name="email"     type="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>
            <label>Subject</label>
            <textarea  name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate.." required></textarea>
            <button type="submit"></button>  
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: is it possible with the animation I have for handling errors? See the JS code in my code above. I have updated it

Comment: It still didnt work :(

Comment: check my post, I added the js code under `UPDATE2` which will make things easier to see and understand

Comment: any update? The code still does not send responses to the email. I will validate your answer once this gets sorted out please :)

Comment: @user2345 sorry, i had to respond to an emergency at home. I changed the fetch ...

Comment: @user2345 did you noticed my changes to the CSS and HTML parts of your code?

Answer (score 1):

if for some reason you want to keep the `novalidate` you can instead loop through your elements to validate them (there are easier ways but im not sure if you are using any library).

you can do something like that:

```
let valid = true
validateInputs() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#my-form input[type=text]")

    for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
        if (element.value === "")
            valid = false
            break
        }
```

and use that as your status which has no meaning now (thanks to `novalidate`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your form element has the "novalidate" attribute on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem what i see is that your status var is null. Add the element with the id `my-form-status` in your dom then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide which fields and what you will validate. I wrote for you a simple example function how check some field on empty. (For name )

```js
var form = document.getElementById("my-form");
var AllFieldStatus = false;
var statusName = false;
var statusLastName = false;
var statusEmail = false;
var statusTextfield = false;

function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var status = document.getElementById("my-form-status");
  var data = new FormData(event.target);

  //// Validation on empty field
  statusName = checkNameField(document.getElementById("firstname"), statusName);

  /// the same operation with others fields

  if (statusName === false) {
    alert("Field name emty");
    return
  } else {
    console.log("Name not empty");
  }



  fetch(event.target.action, {
    method: form.method,
    body: data,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => {
    status.innerHTML = "Thanks for your submission!";
    form.reset()
  }).catch(error => {
    status.innerHTML = "Oops! There was a problem submitting your form"
  });
}
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)


function checkNameField(field, statusCheck) {

  el = field.value;
  if (el.length > 0) {
    return true;
  }

}
```

```css
/* Contact Form */

input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br />Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="https://formspree.io/f/xdobkgny" id="my-form" method="POST" novalidate>
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your First Name.." required>
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your Last Name.." required>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate.." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

You need check each field on empty status before you will send data. If all

```
statusName = true;
statusLastName = true;
statusEmail = true;
statusTextfield = true;
```

you will send otherwise make return function

Comment: I would like the shake effect on this. Also I updated the js in my code above, can you take a look?